# how can I clearInterval a timer in an another view ,in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, timer, triggers

this is my app [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayking/xh7fc/2/)

this App is a question test.
it has these function below:

1. choose a item,if correct,show some text and a next question link on a popup layer;
2. every question has a second countdown timer, if timeout, return some text;
3. if checked a item in time,the timer would stopped.

now I have trouble with the 3rd item, i don't know how to clearInterval the timer.
who can help me! thanks!

```
var TimerView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#time-value"),
initialize: function () {
    var self = this;
    //console.log(this.model.get("seconds"));
    //this.current = (new Date()).getSeconds();
    var _t = new Date();
    this.end = _t.setSeconds(_t.getSeconds() + Number(this.model.get("seconds")));
    // this.end = (new Date(this.model.getTime() + this.model.seconds * 1000)).getTime();
    this.model.on('change', this.render(), this);


},
cdInterval: '',
startCountdown: function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log('start countdown');
    this.cdInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
        self.render();
    }, 10);

},
stopCountdown: function () {
    console.log('stop countdown222');
    clearInterval(this.cdInterval);
},
render: function () {

    var end = this.end,
        now = (new Date()).getTime(),
        _second = 1000,
        _minute = _second * 60,
        diff = end - now;
    if (diff <= 0) {
        this.stopCountdown();

        //            app.navigate('qid/2', { trigger: true });
        this.$el.html(" 00 : 000 ");
        /*var result = new Result({
            qid: '',
            status: 3
        });*/
        app.result.set({
            qid: app.id,
            status: 3
        });
        /*(new PopupView({
            model:app.result

        })).render();*/
        return false;
    }
   // some code....
}
```

});
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayking/xh7fc/2/)

Comment: You could use events to enable communication between views. Either that or some sort of global timer that you can start and stop from anywhere...

Comment: thanks for your guide,I slove it http://jsfiddle.net/rayking/xh7fc/4/.